# Access WSL2 java vm through IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, wsl-2, graalvm

I have setup GraalVM by downloading it through oracle page and extracting the tar file in drive E:/ (`"E:\Programs\Java\graalvm-ee-java17-22.0.0.2\bin"`).

Then I log into WSL2 (ubuntu) bash and setup the environment variables in bashrc.

[image]

now I can execute the VM through command line...

[image]

However my IDEA Community could not load this JVM into my project. When I try to manually add JDK, it would not allow to open `mnt` folder and specify the path.

[image]

I can't expand the `e` directory. How can I overcome this issue and allow IDEA to recognize the WSL instance JDK?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Windows limitation, if you open `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\mnt` in File Explorer, you will not be able to browse the drives. I'd recommend you install JDK in another browsable place under WSL.

Comment: I tried this. Im getting permission denied when I try to copy jdk folder into linux file system. I tried /usr/... , /etc/... and so on. can you tell me a possible path to copy?